# Unable to call useContext within a functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am able to update the context through the following component:

```
const LightController: React.FC<LightControllerInterface> = ({ devices }) => {
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

  const handleFoo1 = () => {
    dispatch({
      key: 'foo1',
      data: !state.foo1
    })
  }

  const handleFoo2 = () => {
    dispatch({
      key: 'foo2',
      data: !state.foo2
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleFoo1}>Foo1</button>
      <button onClick={handleFoo2}>Foo2</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

However, since the `handleFoo1` and `handleFoo2` functions are used in multiple components, it would be handy to abstract it and create a shared functional component like the following:

```
//Loader.tsx

export const handleFoo1 = (value) => {
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);
dispatch({
      key: 'foo1',
      data: value
    })
}

export const handleFoo2 = (value) => {
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);
dispatch({
      key: 'foo2',
      data: value
    })
}
```

and it would be used like the following:

```
import {handleFoo1, handleFoo2} from './loader.tsx'
const LightController: React.FC<LightControllerInterface> = ({ devices }) => {
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(AppContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleFoo1(!state.foo1)}>Foo1</button>
      <button onClick={handleFoo2(!state.foo2)}>Foo2</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The first version works alright, but with the abstracted functional component I get the common error:

`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:`

Is there anything here I am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in functions handleFoo1 and handleFoo2 as they don't return react element and react doesn't consider them as react functional components

"This function is a valid React component because it accepts a single “props” (which stands for properties) object argument with data and returns a React element." https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

that's why you get such an error 'Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:'

maybe it is better to pass dispatch to that functions as second parameters

```
export const handleFoo1 = (value, dispatch) => {
dispatch({
      key: 'foo1',
      data: value
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I had tried it already and it works even though it is no so clean, because with this abstraction I want to avoid passing a lot of arguments all the time. Furthermore, if I try to use `useEffect` inside of this component it throws an error too.

Comment: Yes, you can't use useEffect by the same reason, as your functions don't return react elements, react doesn't recognize them as a react component, and that's why you can't use any hooks in such functions. Sorry for my English)